# Creating a dictionary: Method to prevent the same word from being added more than once

Tags: java, arrays, string, dictionary

I need to create a method to determine whether or not the word I'm trying to add to my String[] dictionary has already been added. We were not allowed to use ArrayList for this project, only arrays.

I started out with this

```
public static boolean dictHasWord(String str){
    for(int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++){
       if(str.equals(dictionary[i])){
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, my professor told me not to use this, because it is a linear function O(n), and is not effective. What other way could I go about solving this method?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Arrays class? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: What data structures have you learned about that you might be allowed to use?  There are a couple obvious answers, but if they involve data structures you've been learning about, then this is a test to make sure you've learned it and I'm hesitant to give you the answer; and if you haven't learned about them, it's too much to expect you to figure them out on your own.  It's hard to answer a problem like this without knowing the real restrictions and the rest of the context.

Comment: We are only allowed to create our dictionary using an array of Strings. No ArrayList or anything like that. The only other restrictions are we cannot call Arrays.sort() or Arrays.binarySearch().

Comment: We are reading the words from 3 seperate text files that contain full length books and then creating a String[] dictionary that we will end up sorting and putting into it's own file dictionary.txt. We cannot add the same word in our dictionary twice, the length of the word must be > 1, and the word cannot start with a Capital letter. I just need to make this method work more effectively. It was working with what i previously had.

Comment: Search for words based on consecutive characters.  You only need to  compare to the dictionary entries starting with the first letter as the new word. This dramatically reduces  the search/comparison  time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of how to quickly search through a Array with good readability. I would suggest using this method to search your array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] list = {"name", "ryan"
    };
    //returns boolean here
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(list).contains("ryan"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's still an O(n) solution.

Comment: define O(n) solution? is this another term for linear search?

Comment: i would look into a recursive way to sort if you aren't looking for linear

Comment: O(n) means it runs in time proportional to "n".  A linear search is one example of an O(n) algorithm.  And the `contains()` method on a `List` is a linear search.

Comment: when i used the for loop in my method, if it is it's worst case, i would have to search through every element in the array. Therefore its big o notation is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class as part of your assignment, you can sort your array and use a binary search instead, which is not O(n).

```
public static boolean dictHasWord(String str){
  if(Arrays.binarySearch(dictionary, str) != -1){
     return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Just keep in mind you must sort first.

EDIT:
Regarding writing your own implementation, here's a [sample](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8388/java-binary-search-and-get-index-if-not-there-review) to get you going. Here are the [javadocs for compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) as well. Heres [another sample](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3343/recursion/binsearch.html) (int based example) showing the difference between recursive and non recursive, specifically in Java.

Comment: Yeah, we can use the arrays class, however we cannot call Arrays.sort or use it's search method

Comment: We have to make our own sort method, and then call our sort method right after each word gets added.

Comment: Based on your comment above, it sounds like you have everything you need except for the actual search method, but you aren't able to use one that's already provided. Why not implement your own? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsSearch/article.html#binarysearch_implementation

Comment: Ok, we have learned binarySearch. I understand the link you just posted, however, now i am searching for whether or not the String has been added yet. How would i implement binary search using Strings, instead of integers.

Comment: Added a sample. There's some comments that link regarding code quality and how the algorithm works that are also useful. Also included the Javadoc for .compareTo, as its important in this case to understand how all of this fits together.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it maybe an overkill in this case, but a hash-table would not be O(n).

This uses the fact that every String can be turnt into an int via `hashCode()`, and equal strings will produce the same hash.

Our dictionary can be declared as:

```
LinkedList<String>[] dictionary;
```

In other words in each place several strings may reside, this is due to possible collisions (different strings producing the same result).

The simplest solution for addition would be:

```
public void add(String str)
{
  dictionary[str.hashCode()].add(str);
}
```

But in order to do this, you would need to make an array size equal to 1 less the maximum of `hashCode()` function. Which is probably too much memory for you. So we can do a little differently:

```
public void add(String str)
{
  dictionary[str.hashCode()%dictionary.length].add(str);
}
```

This way we always mod the hash. For best results you should make your dictionary size some prime number, or at least a power of a single prime.

Then when you want to test the existence of the string you do exactly what you had in the original, but you use the specific `LinkedList` that you get from the hash:

```
public static boolean dictHasWord(String str)
{
    for(String existing : dictionary[str.hashCode()%dictionary.length])
    {
       if(str.equals(existing)){
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

At which point you may ask "Isn't it O(n)?". And the answer is that it is not, since the hash function did not take into consideration the number of elements in array. The more memory you will give to your array, less collisions you will have, and more this approach moves towards O(1).

---

If somebody finds this answer searching for a real solution (not homework assignment). Then just use `HashMap`.